# Continuous measure from one specimen. Is there an effect of our intervention? [R]

Tags: r, continuous-data

We have a case report, where an intervention could influence the parameters. We have continuous data (1 Hz) and intervention happens two times during the measurement period.

I have depicted the data below, where the red is “no intervention” and the blue is “intervention”.
[image]

Is it possible to calculate if there is a significant effect of the intervention on this one specimen?

Comment: Are you considering any threshold value to be attained to be considered as "influencing the parameters"?

Comment: Do you mean if a change is clinically significant? If so, this is only a case report and we want to hypothesize if a future trial should be setup, so even the smallest effect is relevant